# Bug with outputting long numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```
var q = 10000000000000011;
console.log(q);
```

Output will be:

```
10000000000000012
```

If I try to output `10000000000000010` or `10000000000000012`, everything is fine.
Conversion to string doesn't help either.
How can I avoid this bug?

Comment: Javascript can not represent such big numbers accurately - instead it will convert to closest even number. There are various libraries for handling big numbers.

Comment: Thank you guys for quick response. Link which helped me with the case https://github.com/MikeMcl/big.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum safe integer in JavaScript (2^53 - 1). which is 9007199254740991. You will need to use a big integer library to store such large numbers

Comment: `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

Comment: I'll leave this here, someone might find it useful ... or not.. http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, the maximum integer size in JS is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (9007199254740991)

So if you want larger numbers, you'll have to get creative and use something like scientific notation:

```
10000000000000011 ~= 1 × 10^9 (1e9)
```